# PayPal - different SeverityCode for same error

Tags: paypal

We have a few sites that use PayPal Express (via SOAP). On all but one, if the DoExpressCheckoutPayment returns the following message:

```
10413: "The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts."
```

Then it is classed as an error, and the Ack field is 'Failure', and the Error.SeverityCode is 'Error'.

However, on one site (using a completely different PayPal account), the same error message returns 'SuccessWithWarning' as the Ack and 'Warning' for the Error.SeverityCode.

I can't find a setting that would control whether this error is a SuccessWithWarning or an Error. Does anyone know why I've receive different responses for the same error?